# Get Gitlab user from an access token

Tags: gitlab, access-token

I have a user access token. I would like to know to which user this token belongs.
How can I do that?

PS: I have administrator rights on a self-hosted Gitlab CE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/user` endpoint.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN>" https://gitlab-domain.com/api/v4/user
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#list-current-user-for-normal-users

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. However, I have to mention this doesn't work if the token doesn't have access to api scope (I get a 401).

Comment: If you have access to the GitLab Rails console you can run the following:


token = PersonalAccessToken.find_by_token("<token>")

puts token.user